# Unable to link openssl libraries to CLion C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, openssl, clion

I have a [CLion project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/meet-clion.html). Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Project)

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
> include_directories(/usr/include/openssl/) 
> link_libraries(openssl)
> set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Includes.h b.cpp b.h a.cpp
> a.h) add_executable(Project ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And here is error that I get:

```
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable Project /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Make sure you have the library on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: And how to check LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Is it a system variable?

Comment: me@lnx:~# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH  -- It is empty

Comment: There are two OpenSSL libraries. One is *`libcrypto.so`*, and the other is *`libssl.so`*. ***`link_libraries(openssl)`*** should call out ***`ssl crypto`*** in that order. I don't know how to do it in Cmake, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try link_libraries(ssl) instead of link_libraries(openssl), if you're sure of openssl installed on your local machine.
See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API , it says that "OpenSSL provides two primary libraries: libssl and libcrypto.".

To fix your issue just add to your **CMakeList.txt**:

```
link_libraries(crypto)
```

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Project/Connect.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'ERR_load_crypto_strings@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Then try to link libcrypto also.

Comment: cannot find -llibcrypto

Comment: Oh, just "crypto", like what you have done to "libssl", the prefix "lib" is always not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following LDFLAGS in your Makefile:

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: I don't have openssl in /usr/lib/

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a problem similar to this where CLion was telling me the project could not find my OpenSSL installation. `#include` was not recognizing OpenSSL.

I found this and it worked for me to link OpenSSL to my CLion project.

Add this to `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# Search OpenSSL
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(OPENSSL REQUIRED openssl)

if( OPENSSL_FOUND )

    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS "Using OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
else()
    # Error; with REQUIRED, pkg_search_module() will throw an error by it's own
endif()
```